# Filtering a MariaDB SQL table for the sum of values in a column grouped by dept_name

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have an SQL table that I'm trying to write a Query for. The table has four columns, course_id, title, dept_name and credits. Every course is different and has a unique name, but many of the courses share dept_name. Each course has between 1 and 4 credits.

[Complete Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddK5x.png)

The query I'm trying to write needs to first combine the rows that have the same dept_name, and then only display the resulting departments and credit amounts with a credit sum below 30.

By using the following Query I'm able to return the credit sum grouped by dept_name, but I can't seem to only return the dept_names with a sum of less than 30. Can anyone help me out here? I've tried adding additional WHERE statements, but I just receive errors. Please let me know if this is enough or if more info is needed.

[Half-Filtered Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMz4z.png)

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). Don't post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HAVING`. For example:

```
select deptname, sum(credits) 
from bk_course 
group by dept_name
having sum(credits) < 30
```